# How to get permission to clipboard for firefox?

Tags: javascript, firefox, browser

i need to get permission to clipboard for firefox for this code.

```js
const pasteFromBuffer = document.querySelector('.paste-button');
const textareaPaste = document.querySelector('.input');

pasteFromBuffer.addEventListener('click', () => {
  navigator.clipboard.readText().then(
    clipText => {
      textareaPaste.innerText += clipText;
    }
  );
});
```

```html
<input class="input"></input>
<button class="paste-button">Paste</button>
```

Comment: According to the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Clipboard_API) it will be automatically requested when the page is active (and in focus)

Comment: If you know a bit of rust you could try to shim in [there](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1619251) with a PR that would add it. (FF still doesn't support async-reading)